# Does Mongoose Actually Validate the Existence of An Object Id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I like the validation that comes with Mongoose. We are trying to figure out whether we want to use it, and put up with the overhead. Does anyone know if providing a reference to the parent collection when creating a mongoose schema, (in the child schema, specify the object id of the parent object as a field,) does this then mean that every time you try to save the document it checks the parent collection for the existence of the refereneced object id?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm doing it with middleware, performing a search of the element on validation:

```
ExampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    parentId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Example'
    }

});

ExampleModel = mongoose.model('Example', ExampleSchema);

ExampleSchema.path('parentId').validate(function (value, respond) {

    ExampleModel.findOne({_id: value}, function (err, doc) {
        if (err || !doc) {
            respond(false);
        } else {
            respond(true);
        }
    });

}, 'Example non existent');
```

Comment: What is respond? I don't see it in the docs and "respond"  didn't work for me. I got "respond is not a function" when I tried it. Docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#validation-errors

Answer (score 18):

I'm using [mongoose-id-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-id-validator). Works good

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var idValidator = require('mongoose-id-validator');

var ReferencedModel = new mongoose.Schema({name: String});

var MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  referencedObj : { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ReferencedModel'},
  referencedObjArray: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ReferencedModel' }]
});

MySchema.plugin(idValidator);
```

Comment: I like that. Nice and simple.

Comment: It's last publish was 16 days ago. Still updated till today, good one!

Comment: @ThinhNV sadly it was updated 3 years ago now

Answer (score 3):

No, an `ObjectId` field that's defined in your schema as a reference to another collection is not checked as existing in the referenced collection on a save.  You could do it in Mongoose middleware, if needed.

Comment: Makes sense. We are going with performance, assuming we are coding properly and would NOT enter in a non-existence object id. That of course has it's own risk, but we are rewriting from java into node to match the rest of our architecture, and hopefully solve some serious performance problems we were having.

Answer (score 2):

I found this thread very helpful and this is what I came up with:

This Middleware (I think its one anyway please let me know if not) I wrote checks the referenced model for the id provided in the field.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = (value, respond, modelName) => {
    return modelName
        .countDocuments({ _id: value })
        .exec()
        .then(function(count) {
            return count > 0;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            throw err;
        });
};
```

Example model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User = require('./User');
const Cart = require('./Cart');
const refIsValid = require('../middleware/refIsValid');

const orderSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, default: Date.now, unique: true },
    customerRef: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    cartRef: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Cart', required: true },
    total: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    city: { type: String, required: true },
    street: { type: String, required: true },
    deliveryDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    ccLastDigits: { type: String, required: true },
});

orderSchema.path('customerRef').validate((value, respond) => {
    return refIsValid(value, respond, User);
}, 'Invalid customerRef.');

orderSchema.path('cartRef').validate((value, respond) => {
    return refIsValid(value, respond, Cart);
}, 'Invalid cartRef.');

orderSchema.path('ccLastDigits').validate(function(field) {
    return field && field.length === 4;
}, 'Invalid ccLastDigits: must be 4 characters');

orderSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('order', orderSchema);
```

I'm a very new dev so any feedback is greatly valued!

Comment: Great! that Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Note: this only validates the existence of the relation when writing the `ObjectId`. This does not ensure the relation is not deleted at a later stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/lackey-mongoose-ref-validator (I'm the developer)

It also prevents deletion if the reference is used on another document.

```
var mongooseRefValidator = require('lackey-mongoose-ref-validator');
mongoSchema.plugin(mongooseRefValidator, {
    onDeleteRestrict: ['tags']
});
```

It's an early version, so some bugs are expected. Just fill in a ticket if you find any.

Comment: Are you still maintaining this ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I had the same problem and I came up with a more "modern" solution.
I'm not an expert myself, hope I'm not misleading anyone, but this seems to work:

for example, in a simple "notes" schema, which contains a user field:

```
const noteSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  text: String
});
```

here's the middleware that checks if the userId exists:

```
noteSchema.path('user').validate(async (value) => {
  return await User.findById(value);
}, 'User does not exist');
```